# Jquery:: Calling functions twice in nested <div>?

Tags: jquery, function

I have this code:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div id="child1"></div> <!-- Which is a close button -->
</div>
```

And my jquery

```
$("#parent1").click(function(){
    // Enlarge the image to 1000px
})

$("#child1").click(function(){
    // Stop the animation
    $("#parent1").stop();
    // restore the width to original one: 320px
})
```

The problem now is, when I click the "close button", it calls both function, and it does not restore the  to original width. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or [event.stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling.

Example -

```
$("#child1").click(function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // Stop the animation
    $("#parent1").stop();
    // restore the width to original one: 320px
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6GB/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#child1").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Stop the animation
    $("#parent1").stop();

    // restore the width to original one: 320px
})
```

The event is currently being bubbled up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Restore the width of close button on click of #child1

```
$("#child1").click(function(event){
    $("#parent1").stop();
    $("#parent1").css("width","320px");
    //or
    //event.stopPropagation();
})
```